# How to add pagination in array's foreach loop

Tags: arrays, loops, foreach, pagination

I need help to add pagination to this (3 elements per page).
i'm using it in a wordpress page:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1830805, 1830820, 1830756, 1830750); // these IDs could be a lot in future so i need to paginate them, 3 per page
foreach ($arr as &$value) { ?>

    [...]
   <img src="<?php the_field('apple_watch', $value); ?>">
    [...]


<?php }
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
?>
```